# How to mix monadic constructs in a single Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, monads

I have a toy implementation of a Maybe monad in C# and have implemented the relevant SelectMany extension methods to work with Linq. I stumbled upon a problem when I tried to mix IEnumerable and IMaybe in a single Linq statement.

The Maybe monad looks like

```
public interface IMaybe<T>
{
    bool HasValue { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public static class Maybe
{
    class SomeImpl<T>: IMaybe<T> // obvious implementation snipped for brevity
    class NoneImpl<T>: IMaybe<T> // obvious implementation snipped for brevity

    // methods to construct the Maybe monad
    public static Wrap<T> Some<T>(T value);
    public static Wrap<T> Some<T>(T? value) where T: struct;
    public static IMaybe<T> None<T>();

    public static IMaybe<B> SelectMany<A, B>(this IMaybe<A> a, Func<A, IMaybe<B>> mapFn)
    {
        if (a.HasValue)
            return mapFn(a.Value);
        else
            return None<B>();
    }

    public static IMaybe<C> SelectMany<A, B, C>(
        this IMaybe<A> a, Func<A, IMaybe<B>> mapFn, Func<A, B, C> selector)
    {
        if (a.HasValue)
        {
            var b = mapFn(a.Value);
            if (b.HasValue)
                return Some(selector(a.Value, b.Value));
            else
                return None<C>();
        }
        else
            return None<C>();
    }
}
```

My program tries to read a file, parse the content into a number of URI entries, and for each of the entries download the content from the URI. Exactly how these operations are implemented is irrelevant. The trouble I have lies in the chaining these operations in a Linq statement. I.e.

```
    static IMaybe<string> ReadFile(string path);
    static IMaybe<KeyValuePair<string, Uri>[]> ParseEntries(string input);
    static IMaybe<string> Download(Uri location);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = // IEnumerable<IMaybe<anonymous type of {Key, Content}>>
            from fileContent in ReadFile(args[0])
            from entries     in ParseEntries(fileContent)
            from entry       in entries                   // this line won't compile
            from download    in Download(entry.Value)
            select new { Key = entry.Key, Content = download };

        // rest of program snipped off for brevity
    }
```

The error in question complains about mixing the IMaybe and IEnumerable monads. In its exact wording:

> Error 1   An expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[]' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'MonadicSharp.IMaybe'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.  C:\Dev\Local\MonadicSharp\MonadicSharp\Program.cs   142 31  MonadicSharp

How do I get around this?

Comment: Ok perhaps I am just hitting the limit of my knowledge here. I am going back to read about monad transformer and Haskell. I'll further comment this question when I get a clue.

Comment: Just a little hint - I would simplify by avoiding `IMaybe<T>` and just have a concrete type of `Maybe<T>`. It make sense that many things can implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but I can't think of a need for multiple implementations of `IMaybe<T>`. Can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've concluded that it is just impossible to mix monads in a single LINQ statement so I decided to break it into two statements. This is how it works:

First off, I need to make a slight change to the IMaybe interface declaration to use covariance:

```
public interface IMaybe<out T>{ ... }
```

Next, I need some helper method to transform the IMaybe monad to the IEnumerable monad:

```
public static IEnumerable<IMaybe<T>> UnfoldAll<T>(
    this IMaybe<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    if (source.HasValue)
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(i => Maybe.None<T>());
    else
        return source.Value.Select(value => Maybe.Some(value));
}
```

And finally, I will break the original LINQ statement into two statements (nesting LINQ expressions works too)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = args[0];
    var theEntries =
        from fileContent in ReadFile(path)
        from entries in ParseEntries(fileContent)
        select entries;

    var theContents = 
        from entry in theEntries.UnfoldAll() 
        where entry.HasValue 
        select Download(entry.Value.Value);

    foreach (var content in theContents)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first LINQ statement works on IMaybe monad and the second one on the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the issue lies in the signature for `ParseEntries`.

It currently is:

```
static IMaybe<KeyValuePair<string, Uri>[]> ParseEntries(string input);
```

Perhaps it should be?

```
static IMaybe<KeyValuePair<string, Uri>>[] ParseEntries(string input);
```

So instead of a maybe of array it should be an array of maybe.

Comment: This is very close to my solution. The basic semantics of ParseEntries is to either return an array of entries, if the input conforms to certain grammar, or else return nothing so the signature of the method still stands. As you'll see, I settled on introducing another method to transform an IMaybe<T[]> to IMaybe<T>[]. This is akin to the reverse of Task.WhenAll, which transforms Task<T>[] to Task<T[]>. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because `entries` is of type `IMaybe<T>` and not of type `IEnumerable<T>`.
Have you tried something like this:

```
from entry       in entries.Value
```

Of course this is not what the purpose of a Monad is, but this should be the first step.

Comment: entries is of type KeyValuePair<string, Uri>[] so this won't compile. Remember the closure is introduced by the SelectMany extension method and it is already "unwrapped". The real problem is there is no generic way to mix monads as the semantics of doing so is not well-defined.